# Intelligent spell-checking in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, spell-checking

By default, the results of running `M-x ispell-buffer` in org-mode are
very disappointing.

1. Ispell looks inside `:PROPERTY:` drawers, which commonly contain things like

   ```
   :ID:       797495bd-581b-4a42-883b-c2a55a08f08a
   ```
2. It tries to correct org statements! For instance, it complains about the `SRC` in

   ```
   #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
   ```
3. It goes inside org-blocks. I suppose this might be useful for
   blocks like `#+BEGIN_QUOTE`, but in source code blocks that’s just
   silly.

**Is there a package that fixes all this?**

I’d love to spell-check my writing but the amount of false-positives
I’m getting makes it unfeasible.

*If it matters, the OS's spell checker is aspell.*

Comment: There is a flyspell predicate for org-mode (check `(get 'org-mode 'flyspell-mode-predicate)`), but I'm not sure how that could be generalised for `ispell-buffer`.

Comment: @legoscia Ispell has a variable called `ispell-parser`, so flyspell's predicate might work well there with a wrapper around it.

Comment: I use flyspell and hunspell and I don't see that behavior. Anything in lines with `#+` or in source code blocks is not spell-checked. But normal text under headings is checked. I have these in my flyspell setup: `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode)`, `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook  'turn-on-flyspell)`

Comment: @kaushalmodi Yeah, flyspell is smarter than ispell. Unfortunately, flyspell is a little demanding for my laptops processing power :(. It's not unusable, but it's a little annoying, which is why I was trying ispell.

Comment: @Malabarba unfortunately `ispell-parser` appears to be just a symbol, and code all over the place checks it for particular values. So nothing really extensible.

Comment: @Sigma Shame. I might just have to resign to using flyspell. :-(

Comment: @Malabarba and @Sigma: One option could be to use the `flyspell-lazy` package in addition to `flyspell` which relegates spell-checking to idle periods. I've found this significantly speeded up Org-mode file editing with flyspell on (I got some unacceptable pauses before using this package). You have to tolerate spelling errors not appearing immediately, but I've not found that a significant problem.

Comment: I was just searching for a flyspell solution myself for your point 3. The solution described [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2012-12/msg00764.html) works well for me, but I'm not sure how helpful it is to you.

Comment: Have you seen `Can I prevent ispell from checking source blocks?` in http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As [rvf0068 suggested](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/450/intelligent-spell-checking-in-org-mode#comment1421_450), ispell can be configured to skip over regions that match regexes.  For example, to skip over `:PROPERTIES:` and `:LOGBOOK:` drawers as well as `SRC` blocks, you could put this in your `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'ispell-skip-region-alist '(":\\(PROPERTIES\\|LOGBOOK\\):" . ":END:"))
(add-to-list 'ispell-skip-region-alist '("#\\+BEGIN_SRC" . "#\\+END_SRC"))
```

<sub>(I'm new to StackExchange, so if I've broken etiquette or rules by expanding on rvf0068's answer please let me know.)</sub>

Comment: I don't mind at all, thanks for the further elaboration. :)

Comment: Here are what I wanted ispell to ignore: https://github.com/grettke/home/blob/master/TC3F.org

Comment: That's useful, but too big a hammer for me. I often have notes in my LOGBOOK that I would want to be spool chucked.

Comment: The regions that I exclude: https://github.com/grettke/home/blob/master/ALEC.org#L4546

Comment: Is capital letters important or could I also use `begin_src`?

Answer (score 9):

If you use `flyspell` instead, see [How does one use flyspell in org buffers without flyspell triggering on tangled code blocks?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/how-does-one-use-flyspell-in-org-buffers-without-flyspell-triggering-on-tangled/9347)

*Please note:* `ispell-skip-region-alist` is **NOT** used by `flyspell`.