# How does one use flyspell in org buffers without flyspell triggering on tangled code blocks?

Tags: org-mode, flyspell

Imagine an org buffer in Emacs like:

```
* Title

Some text describing the title and the codew (sic) and whatnot.

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs_lisp
(setq backup-by-copying t)
#+END_SRC
```

I want flyspell to check the org buffer (and catch the spelling error in it) but ignore the content between the #+BEGIN_SRC and #+END_SRC marks. How does one go about that?

Comment: It looks like someone will need to write up some code using the `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate`, if that hasn't already been invented.  Here is a related thread for flyspell using the `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate`:  http://superuser.com/a/345461/206164 ; and, here is a semi-related thread for ispell using `ispell-skip-region-alist`, but not relating to flyspell:  http://www.emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2103/2287

Comment: can http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2103/2609 help?

Comment: This question is a dupe of that one https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/450/intelligent-spell-checking-in-org-mode/2103#2103

Comment: @grettke: Seems like a dupe, but it's not. Changing the settings for Ispell does not actually solve the problem in Flyspell. At least not when I tried it.

Comment: It works out of the box in v8.3 when you require `ox`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
;; NO spell check for embedded snippets
(defadvice org-mode-flyspell-verify (after org-mode-flyspell-verify-hack activate)
  (let* ((rlt ad-return-value)
         (begin-regexp "^[ \t]*#\\+begin_\\(src\\|html\\|latex\\|example\\|quote\\)")
         (end-regexp "^[ \t]*#\\+end_\\(src\\|html\\|latex\\|example\\|quote\\)")
         (case-fold-search t)
         b e)
    (when ad-return-value
      (save-excursion
        (setq b (re-search-backward begin-regexp nil t))
        (if b (setq e (re-search-forward end-regexp nil t))))
      (if (and b e (< (point) e)) (setq rlt nil)))
    (setq ad-return-value rlt)))
```

Please note ispell-skip-region-alist is NOT used by flyspell.

Test on Emacs24.3, 24.4, 24.5, 25.1 with builtin org-mode

Most users turn on flyspell by default. So above code is enough.

But I don't enable flyspell-mode in org file. I prefer manually `M-x flyspell-buffer` again and again. So I need `(flyspell-mode 1) (flyspell-mode -1)` in org-mode-hook. Yes, turn on then turn off flyspell-mode. The purpose is to make sure the org-mode's default predicate is loaded.

Please note `flyspell-incorrect-hook` is not the good place for per major mode configuration because it's shared by all major modes. So the heavy weight configuration code in one major mode could impact other major modes if the per major mode code is placed in `flyspell-incorrect-hook`.

`flyspell` has already provided `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate`  which is "Function providing per-mode customization over which words are flyspelled". It's buffer local variable so it safe to use out of box.

Screenshot of its definition from `flyspell.el`:

[image]

Besides, the predicate is more flexible than the hook because **the predicate is tested at first**. So if the predicate claims a word is not a typo, the hook will not be executed. Here is the screenshot of `flyspell-word` definition,

[image]

Actually, the default value of `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` in `org-mode` is `org-mode-flyspell-verify`.

The reason I advice `org-mode-flyspell-verify` is I'm lazy. I could change the value of the predicate to my own function which calls `org-mode-flyspell-verify` instead,

```
(defun org-mode-hook-setup ()
  (setq flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate
        (lambda ()
          (let* ((rlt (org-mode-flyspell-verify)))
            ;; do whatever on rlt below this line
            (message "rlt=%s" rlt)
            rlt))))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-mode-hook-setup)
```

Comment: I suggest adding quote to the regexp, such as:
`    
    (begin-regexp "^[ \t]*#\\+begin_\\(src\\|html\\|latex\\|quote\\)")
    (end-regexp "^[ \t]*#\\+end_\\(src\\|html\\|latex\\|quote\\)")`