# How to make Flyspell ignore code blocks in Markdown?

Tags: flyspell, markdown-mode

Can I filter what Flyspell may check in the buffer? I don't want it to spell-check code in Markdown mode.

Maybe I can use the font-face at point for that? Something like this:

```
(let ((get-char-property (point) 'face))
  (when (equal face "markdown-pre-face")
    ;; no spell-check
    ))
```

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9347/2332) is similar, but the solution there works only for Org-mode.

Comment: You can use C-u C-x = to inspect the faces at point inside a Markdown code block.

Comment: @lunaryorn in my markdown-mode, the code is all the same font (`markdown-pre-face`). The question is how to pass that info to Flyspell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The accepted answer for org-mode is written by me. org-mode is tricky because its own check-word-predicate is already defined.

markdown is simpler because it uses default predicate provided by flyspell-mode,

```
(defun flyspell-generic-textmode-verify ()
  "Used for `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate' in text modes."
  ;; (point) is next char after the word. Must check one char before.
  (let ((f (get-text-property (- (point) 1) 'face)))
    (not (memq f '(markdown-pre-face)))))

(setq flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate 'flyspell-generic-textmode-verify)
(flyspell-mode 1)
```

By the way, `M-x describe-function ENTER flyspell-prog-mode ENTER`, you will find similar setup.

Use the Source, Luke.

Comment: How cool! Actually, I did `describe-function` with Helm and filtered by `flyspell verify`, but somehow missed `flyspell-generic-textmode-verify`. Thanks!

Comment: `flyspell-generic-textmode-verify` does not exist in flyspell-mode, it's defined by me. So you need insert its definition into ~/.emacs.

Comment: Oh, true. I've checked it, and it works beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to chen bin, I have added a `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` function to Markdown mode.  If you're using the latest development version, or use the next release version, then you won't have to use local modifications to achieve this.

For those curious, perhaps to implement a predicate for another mode, the current function is below.  It checks for code blocks, inline code, and comments using functions defined by Markdown mode.  It also checks for certain faces to ignore: reference labels, Markdown markup, and URLs.

```el
    (defun markdown-flyspell-check-word-p ()
      "Return t if `flyspell' should check word just before point.
    Used for `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate'."
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (1- (point)))
        (not (or (markdown-code-block-at-point-p)
                 (markdown-inline-code-at-point-p)
                 (markdown-in-comment-p)
                 (let ((faces (get-text-property (point) 'face)))
                   (if (listp faces)
                       (or (memq 'markdown-reference-face faces)
                           (memq 'markdown-markup-face faces)
                           (memq 'markdown-url-face faces))
                     (memq faces '(markdown-reference-face
                                   markdown-markup-face
                                   markdown-url-face))))))))
```

Note that the `face` property may be a list, so this function handles that case as well.