# Skip flyspell checking of ~code~ and =verbatim= regions in Org mode

Tags: org-mode, flyspell, spell-checking

First some disambiguation:

- [This Endless Parentheses page](https://endlessparentheses.com/ispell-and-org-mode.html) demonstrates how to use `ispell-skip-region-alist` to skip `=code=` and `=verbatim=` blocks with ispell…

  ```
  (defun endless/org-ispell ()
    "Configure `ispell-skip-region-alist' for `org-mode'."
    (make-local-variable 'ispell-skip-region-alist)
    (add-to-list 'ispell-skip-region-alist '(org-property-drawer-re))
    (add-to-list 'ispell-skip-region-alist '("~" "~"))
    (add-to-list 'ispell-skip-region-alist '("=" "="))
    (add-to-list 'ispell-skip-region-alist '("^#\\+BEGIN_SRC" . "^#\\+END_SRC")))
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'endless/org-ispell)
  ```

  …however, `flyspell` does not use `ispell-skip-region-alist`.
- [This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9347/594) on Emacs SX demonstrates how to skip flyspell checking for source blocks…

  ```
  ;; NO spell check for embedded snippets
  (defadvice org-mode-flyspell-verify (after org-mode-flyspell-verify-hack activate)
    (let* ((rlt ad-return-value)
           (begin-regexp "^[ \t]*#\\+begin_\\(src\\|html\\|latex\\|example\\|quote\\)")
           (end-regexp "^[ \t]*#\\+end_\\(src\\|html\\|latex\\|example\\|quote\\)")
           (case-fold-search t)
           b e)
      (when ad-return-value
        (save-excursion
          (setq b (re-search-backward begin-regexp nil t))
          (if b (setq e (re-search-forward end-regexp nil t))))
        (if (and b e (< (point) e)) (setq rlt nil)))
      (setq ad-return-value rlt)))
  ```

  …but not for inline code and verbatim region.

How can I achieve the `ispell` solution for `flyspell`, where Flyspell skips any regions surrounded by `~` or `=`? Generally I use these for things like variable names, which naturally tend to fail spellchecking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this works out-of-the box with Emacs 26.3 and Orgmode 9.1.9. Source blocks and code snippets are not highlighted by `flyspell` with that Orgmode version. Maybe, you should just update.

To address the general problem:

You can ignore corrections proposed by flyspell by adding a function to `flyspell-incorrect-hook`. This hook already exists since Emacs 21.1. So it should be available even if you use an Emacs that old (for whatever reason).

I cite here the doc-string of `flyspell-incorrect-hook`:

> List of functions to be called when incorrect words are encountered.
>   Each function is given three arguments.  The first two
>   arguments are the beginning and the end of the incorrect region.
>   The third is either the symbol ‘doublon’ or the list
>   of possible corrections as returned by ‘ispell-parse-output’.
>
> If any of the functions return non-nil, the word is not highlighted as
>   incorrect.

It is easy to detect source blocks and code snippets with `org-element-context`.

Here comes the code that skips flyspell on source blocks and code snippets:

```el
(defun org+-flyspell-skip-code (b e _ignored)
  "Returns non-nil if current word is code.
This function is intended for `flyspell-incorrect-hook'."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char b)
    (memq (org-element-type (org-element-context))
      '(code src-block))))

(defun org+-config-flyspell ()
  "Configure flyspell for org-mode."
  (add-hook 'flyspell-incorrect-hook #'org+-flyspell-skip-code nil t))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org+-config-flyspell)
```

Tested on Emacs 26.3.

Comment: I'm on Org version 9.2.3, which does not seem to skip those regions by default. Your solution is the cleanest I've seen, since it uses a purpose-built hook rather than an advice wrapper. Thank you!

Comment: you could easily mix up the multiple major mode's spell setup and slow down the Emacs. `flyspell-incorrect-hook` is only for light weight and generic setup. See my updated answer

Comment: @chenbin `#'org+-flyspell-skip-code` is added [buffer locally](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Hooks.html) to `flyspell-incorrect-hook`. So there is no interference with other major modes. Let the OP decide whether the performance is a killer argument. Aspell is a background process that keeps running when it is started once. Therefore there is not so much overhead as one would guess at the first sight.

Comment: @Tobias, it's better to use the variable `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` which is buffer local out of box so user has not chance to to make the mistake. Besides, `flyspell-incorrect-hook` is executed AFTER the predicate. So it can't override predicate's logic.

Comment: @chenbin You are right that `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` should be used. I had a look into `org-compat.el`. There stands `(put 'org-mode 'flyspell-mode-predicate 'org-mode-flyspell-verify)`. This should make flyspell work correctly out of the box. Maybe, we should help Matthew in a chat to identify the problem with his org version.

Comment: See the end of my answer at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/how-does-one-use-flyspell-in-org-buffers-without-flyspell-triggering-on-tangled/9347, use `(setq flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate org-mode-flyspell-verify)` in `org-mode-hook`

Comment: Works with Org 9.4.5 and Emacs 27.2. No more spell checking in `~code~` and `=verbatim=`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check the current font face at point, if it's `org-verbatim` or `org-code`, then set the predicate's return value to nil. So Emacs knows the word at point is NOT a typo.

Here is the function to test font face at point,

```
(defun font-belongs-to (pos fonts)
  "Current font at POS belongs to FONTS."
  (let* ((fontfaces (get-text-property pos 'face)))
    (when (not (listp fontfaces))
      (setf fontfaces (list fontfaces)))
    (delq nil
          (mapcar (lambda (f)
                    (member f fonts))
                  fontfaces))))
```

To use this function, in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9347/594
code, just below `(when ad-return-value`, insert one line,

```
(if (font-belongs-to (point) '(org-verbatim org-code)) (setq rlt nil))
```

BTW, you can check my org setup at https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d/blob/98bef295ac515e5af43716d72a377494646653bf/lisp/init-org.el#L120 . 
The predicate there has more features and its code is more efficient.

**Please note `flyspell-incorrect-hook` is NOT the right place for per mode setup.** I explain the details in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9347/594